# Formatted a partition in windows 10, can't get log in screen in Linux Mint 19

Tags: linux, data-recovery, partitioning

Issue: Formatted an NTFS drive in windows that was created in Linux. Now can only log into Linux in emergency mode and could not see my home folder, sub folders or files in them. I would like to recover the installation ideally or atleast recover home folder. I can log into Windows and work normally.

I have a duel boot T480 laptop with preinstalled Windows 10. Once I bought it, I resized the C:\ drive, using gParted I created additional partition for storage (D:, 50gb and F:, 100gb) and other ext4 partitions and installed Linux Mint 19. I’ve been using this setup for last year or so. D:\ was not being used since its creation using gParted.

Few days ago, while I was logged into windows10, I formatted the unused D:\ drive. The first clue something was wrong was when the partition size was 175gb instead of 50gb that I created. I created one empty folder from windows after I formatted the partition. After this process this is how  my partitions look like.https://imgur.com/pGuTlot. I dont see the windows recovery partition etc.

I tried to log into Mint, I got the grub menu, selected Mint, all I got was a menu saying "You are in emergency mode" message. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKSpO.jpg I could log in as root though. If I restart, I can still log into Windows10 and work normally. I have some files in the home folder that I would like to recover, along with my browser shortcuts.

What I tried:
I have an installation USB and I can log into the machine using that USB.
I can log into Windows10 and work nromally.
Tried testdisk:
This is what I got after first https://imgur.com/lMdwuGu.
The next step was quicksearch. This is what I got after quicksearch https://imgur.com/EpGI1nB. There are many partitions marked with "D"
I tried finding files using option "p", I don't see the files that I'm looking for (my home directory or sub folders like desktop etc).

[image: Test disk output after analysis]

[image: test disk output after analysis]

[image: green checks are windows partitions that are ok, yellow are linux root, red crosses have error messages as "disk damaged"]

[image: Current state of partitions]

Comment: This is not a security question, almost certainly. You might have better luck on Superuser or Unix & Linux stack exchange.

Comment: I see a lot of cut-off pictures and badly readable screenshots. But I'm missing some vital information. Can you give a list  (table) of the partitions as they should be according to you, with their contents? So "p1=EFI system (fat 32) ; P2=MS reserved; p3=Windows C: (ntfs)" etcetera?  It seems that you formatted a partition that is used by Mint and of course, Mint won't boot if its partition has been formatted.